# The convergence of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

I am looking to study the convergence of this integral $$ \int_0^1 \frac{x}{\ln x}$$

One method to prove the convergence is to use the special case of Cauchy definition "what is called in French l'integral de Bertrand" as

The integral $\int_0^{1/e} \frac{1}{x^a (\ln x)^b}$ converges iff $(a <1)$ or ($a=1$ and $b >1$)

so in my question $a=-1$ and the integral converges but I am looking for another method to do so. Is there another simple way to prove the convergence.

Comment: Your integral actually diverges because of the singularity of the integrand around $x=1$.

Comment: Your inequality is not true, the integrand in the LHS is positive and the RHS is negative.

Comment: @user Yes you are right...I see now

Comment: Your original integral converges, but this is because the singularity of the denominator $\ln x$ at $x=1$ is cancelled by the numerator $x-1$. You definitely have to take this effect into consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x}{\ln x}dx=\int_1^\frac12 \frac{x}{\ln x}dx+\int_\frac12^1 \frac{x}{\ln x}dx$$

and since $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x}{\ln x}=0$ all boils down in $\int_\frac12^1 \frac{x}{\ln x}dx$ and by $x=1-y$ we obtain

$$\int_\frac12^1 \frac{x}{\ln x}dx=\int_0^\frac12 \frac{1-y}{\ln (1-y)}dy$$

which **diverges** by limit comparison test with $\int_0^\frac12 \frac1ydy$ indeed

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\frac{1-y}{\ln (1-y)}}{\frac1y}=\lim_{x\to 0^+} (1-y)\frac{y}{\ln (1-y)}=1$$

In a similar way we can prove that for $b>1$

$$\int_0^1 \frac {x} { (\ln x)^b }dx$$

the integral converges.

Comment: thanks a lot. I added an edit as you see above

Comment: Yes I understand now and as you said from the beginning my first inequality not correct. Could you please clarify why $\int_0^1 \frac{x-1}{\ln x}$ converges?

Comment: I know that $\ln (1+x) \sim x$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ and $\ln (x) \sim x-1$ as $x\rightarrow 1$ but how does this enough to show the convergence?

Comment: We have that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x-1}{\ln x}=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{x-1}{\ln x}=1$ therefore it is  a proper integral which converges.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the integral converges ? The integrand is equivalent to $\frac1{x - 1}$ around $1$.

Comment: thanks for your interest . I added an edit

Comment: The observation is fine, maybe you should explain better in which sense it is equivalent.